# how to get mobile number using wechat api in android

Tags: android, accountmanager, whatsapp, wechat

how to get mobile number using wechat api in android.
 We can get mobile number and email-id by using Whatsapp api through this code

```
     AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
     Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
```

So like that is it possible to get mobile number using wechat api ????

Comment: Did u check Wechat [API](http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi/documentation)??

Comment: Ya I check but I didn't get.

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the mobile number of the user. Not through an official account nor through the API as this is a security concern. Not even us at Wechat can get that number. It is kept back for security reasons and spam.

Recently it has become available to get a user's mobile number. This however is only available if the user clicks "allow" to your brand and only if you have integrated with their wallet.

You can however contact WeChat for a merchant account and once that is setup the Merchant API will be supplied to you.

Comment: No you can get mobile number by using whatsapp api.In India mobile number are not registered with mobile devices that's why we can't get mobile number in India.So if you want then you must should have whatsapp installed on your device.

Comment: Is this true? I don't see any WhatsApp API released. Can you point me some links?

Comment: DeverloperX, can you tell me if there is any way to send a Wechat message to a specific mobile number? Eg: the API will take 2 params: phone number and message content, return will be 1. Mobile not registered with Wechat, 2. Sent successfully 3. User is not logged in from any device, thanks!

Comment: can we get the list of friend of a user ?

Comment: DeveloperX we are implementing wechat login on our mobile app. Hence we would have access to both openid and unionid. We also have a linked official account. I would like to know if there is a way for us to send messages to wechat of the users who have logged-in using our app (using the unionid ? even if the user is not following our official account)